# I need any number + a specific number in java

Tags: java

So my problem lies here:

```
    if (foo2/4 == Any Number +0.25){
        jahres_code = zwischenergebnis2%7 ;
    }
```

I constructed that method so that only the number after the comma matters. And I don't know what to write it so that I have any number.

Comment: Come again please?

Comment: ...and while clarifying your problem please also post real Java code, not sort-of kind-of code.

Comment: Well iw won't let me post my full code cause that's apparently too long so I figured I only post the if-expression. As for my problem I will try to clarify it: Ok it lies here: I basically need this as the condition: foo2/4 == x.25 here x can  be any int. This way I thought it wouldn't matter what x is so only the .25 is the number that matters. But I don't know how to write it. For example (foo2 is an input). foo2 = 17. 17/4 = 4.25. But I want this statement to work for any foo2 that /4 is x.25.

Comment: You can post longer code if you also post more text that explains it and your problem well. If the code is still too long, then it's too long.

Comment: I hope my edited comment makes it more understandable.

Comment: Please edit your actual question. Important information should not be buried in comments.

Comment: Are you saying that you are wondering how to get input from the user and stick that input in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you want is `true` in `if` when `foo / 4` is in form of `x.25`. Do this:

```
if (((foo / 4d) - (foo / 4)) == 0.25)
```

What does this do? You have `int` `foo`, so when you divide it with `4` as `int`, you get int so `17 / 4` will give `4`. But when you divide it with `4` as `double` (represented as `4d`), you get `4.25`. Now you take from this a whole number (which you get when you divide `foo` with `int 4`) and if it is `0.25`, you have `true`.

**Note:** you can do this with `double`, but not with `float`, since behavior is different, due its representation in memory.